# Did Mark write for Peter

Tags: new-testament, peter, authorship, mark

I have been told that Peter could not read or write. Mark wrote all of Peters’s stories and scriptures. How can I determine if this true?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone agrees that Peter is described as a fisherman in the area of Galilee. If he was literate at all, he would not be well trained as a writer. However, the letters attributed to Peter come from several decades later, so it is possible that he could have learned to read and write fairly well in the period between Jesus' ministry and the time the letters were written.

About Mark, we have to reject the idea that "all" of Peter's letters were written by him, since 1 Peter 5:12 itself says "through Silvanus, whom I consider a faithful brother, I have written this short letter to encourage you and to testify that this is the true grace of God." It is just one verse later, that Peter refers to "my son Mark."

This apparently close relationship between Mark and Peter led early church authorities to believe that Peter was an eye-witness for the accounts of Mark's Gospel. However it should be noted that the authenticity of both 1 and 2 Peter is disputed, meaning that it is doubted that they were either written by Peter, dictated by him, or even approved by him after having been written by Mark, Silvanus or someone else.

The Wikipedia article on the [Authorship of the Petrine Espistles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Petrine_epistles) gives pro and con arguments on this question, with references for further study.

Comment: Among other things, it is interesting how the Wikipedia article relies on the admission against interest opinion of Danial Wallace on the number of scholars disputing Petrine authorship of the Epistles. However, if I were in charge of the Wikipedia article, I would have not used a quantitative term like "most" when there has been no demonstrable fixed number to refer to. How many scholars are there? How many of those dispute Petrine authorship? Wallace, does not say. If dead scholars from the past are allowed in the calculation, I suspect, an "Argumentum ad Populum" could go either way.